# Discord v12 shows "no send() method on channel" yet it exists

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm using Discordjs v12.5.3 and when I try the following command:

```
client.channels.cache.get("my-channel-id")?.send("Hello World")
```

I get the following error:

```
Property 'send' does not exist on type 'Channel'.ts(2339)
```

it is only when I ignore the error with the following:

```
      //  @ts-ignore
```

My code compiles and runs fine.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was because that method returns a "Channel" type and the actual returned object is an extended class of type "TextChannel" which contains the send method.

Comment: You could cast it as a TextChannel. `(client.channels.cache.get("my-channel-id") as TextChannel).send("Hello World")`